# Difference in solr results (web interface results vs http request results)

Tags: solr

I have a solr query which picks the `solr.StrField` named `UMM_GrundNichtVerfuegbarkeit`. But the results looks different in two different formats. Is there a deep explanation for this ?

### Result 1 (When the query is from Solr web interface):

[image]

### Result 2 (Through normal http call):

[image: from http call]

Why is this difference in results?

Comment: Can you add some details ? the query at least. Where the second screenshot comes from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second entry shows the actual rendered XML response. `&amp;` is the HTML/XML Entity for the ampersand (`&`) and should always be represented with `&amp;` inside an XML document.

Since &..; is used for other escapes as well, escaping `&` is the correct thing to do in XML. It'll be unescaped (i.e. converted back to `&`) by your XML library or as in your case, by the browser.